# How to use Angular controller in Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin, angular-controller

I'm new to Zeppelin, recently I'm study how to use Zeppelin in my current project.  I want to add a Angular controller in Zeppelin paragraph. But it's failed.  Can you please give me some hints how to solve it? Below is my code.

```
println(s"""
%angular
<script>
    angular.module('zeppelinWebApp').controller('myNewController', myNewController);

    function myNewController() {

        var vm = this;
        vm.publicVariable = {};

        // Controller's public functions
        vm.myControllerPublicFunction = myControllerPublicFunction;

        _init();

        function myControllerPublicFunction() {
            publicVariable = publicVariable + 1;
        }

        function _init() {
            vm.myControllerPublicFunction();
        }
    }
</script>

<div ng-controller="myNewController as newCtrl">
  <div ng-click="newCtrl.myControllerPublicFunction" ng-bind='newCtrl.publicVariable'></div>
</div>
""")
```

Answer (score 2):

Been struggling with this myself. The best answer I've come up with is to create a pseudo-controller by grabbing a scoped element using jQuery (based off [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/randerzander/6fec0ff8601bdd6bd25bbefe0847b2d5#file-simple-html)):

```
println(s"""
%angular
<script>
    var element = $('#ctrlHook');
    var scope = angular.element(element.parent('.ng-scope')).scope().compiledScope;


    (function myNewController() {

        var vm = scope;
        vm.publicVariable = 0;

        // Controller's public functions
        vm.myControllerPublicFunction = myControllerPublicFunction;

        _init();

        function myControllerPublicFunction() {
            vm.publicVariable = vm.publicVariable + 1;
        }

        function _init() {
            vm.myControllerPublicFunction();
        }
    })();
</script>

<div id="ctrlHook">
  <div ng-click="myControllerPublicFunction" ng-bind='publicVariable'></div>
</div>
""")
```

You can of course remove the function block and just operate on `scope` directly instead of on `vm`, but I left it in to adhere to your original example as much as possible (I tidied up some variable references where you were calling `publicVariable` instead of `vm.publicVariable` and treating it like a number instead of the object it was initialised as).

**NB**: I cannot confirm whether the variable changes themselves would fix your original code, but I have tested grabbing the scope using the method above and it seems to work. Hope it helps you out.